# How to update .mdb files with a C# web application?

Tags: c#, ms-access, web-applications, oledb, oledbdataadapter

I am writing a app that must have the ability to :

- GUI should be seen on a web interface (Thus I'm using C# Web Application)
- Be able to select .mdb files
- Add rows
- Delete rows
- Edit rows
- Save everything back to the .mdb file.

I have googled for ages.

I have written a similar application in a normal C# windows form application, I used OLEdb to do everything and it worked fine, it wasn't restricted to only one .mdb file.

In the C# Windows Form app I used Gridview control.
As the Web Application doesn't have Gridview, I used a datagrid.

Here is the code is have so far :

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    string databasePath = "____________.mdb";
    DataTable userTable = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
    OleDbConnection connection;
    OleDbCommand command;
    OleDbCommandBuilder builder;
    DataSet ds;
    DataSet tempDs;
    public string DatabaseName = null;
    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=";



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbDatabasePath.Text = databasePath;
    }

    protected void btnLoadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadRecords();
    }

    protected void btnGetTables_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ddTables.Items.Clear();
            ddTables.Text = null;
            getTables();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Could not retrieve the Tables');", true);
        }
    }


    private void getTables()
    {

        string tempstring = "";
        string getTConnection = connectionString + databasePath; ;

        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(getTConnection);

        myConnection.Open();

        DataTable datT = myConnection.GetSchema("Tables");

        for (int i = 0; i < datT.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            tempstring = datT.Rows[i][2].ToString();

            if (tempstring.Contains("MSys"))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                ddTables.Items.Add(datT.Rows[i][2].ToString());
            }
        }
        myConnection.Close();
    }

    private void ReadRecords()
    {
        datagrid.DataSource = null;

        OleDbDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + "Data Source=" + databasePath);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM " + ddTables.Text, connection);
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
            ds = new DataSet("MainDataSet");
            tempDs = new DataSet("TempDataSet");

            connection.Open();
            adapter.Fill(tempDs);
            tempDs.Clear();
            tempDs.Dispose();
            adapter.Fill(ds, ddTables.Text);
            userTable = ds.Tables[ddTables.Text];

        }
        catch
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Could not load the data');", true);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null) reader.Close();
            //if (connection != null) connection.Close();
            datagrid.ShowFooter = true;
        }
        CreateTempTable(0, 10);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('DONE');", true);

    }

    private void ReadRecords2()
    {
       // datagrid.DataSource = null;

        OleDbDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + "Data Source=" + databasePath);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM " + ddTables.Text, connection);
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
            ds = new DataSet("MainDataSet");
            tempDs = new DataSet("TempDataSet");

            connection.Open();
            adapter.Fill(tempDs);
            tempDs.Clear();
            tempDs.Dispose();
            adapter.Fill(ds, ddTables.Text);
            userTable = ds.Tables[ddTables.Text];

        }
        catch
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Could not load the data');", true);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null) reader.Close();
            //if (connection != null) connection.Close();
        }
        CreateTempTable(0, 10);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('DONE');", true);

    }

    private void CreateTempTable(int startRecord, int noOfRecords)
    {
        try
        {
            userTable.Rows.Clear();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "");
            userTable = ds.Tables[""];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Could not load the data in  CreateTempTable');", true);
        }


        datagrid.DataSource = userTable.DefaultView;
        datagrid.DataBind();

    }

    protected void datagrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        datagrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        ReadRecords();

    }

    protected void datagrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void datagrid_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        adapter.Update(userTable);
    }

    protected void datagrid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        adapter.Update(userTable);
        ReadRecords();
    }

    protected void datagrid_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {

       datagrid.EditIndex = -1;
       ReadRecords();

    }

    protected void datagrid_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowToDelete = e.RowIndex;
        datagrid.DeleteRow(rowToDelete);
        adapter.Update(userTable);
        ReadRecords();

    }
}
```

}

It can :

- get the .mdb file
- get the tables in the file and display it
- read the data out of the selected table and display it in the gridview
- add the edit delete buttons

Now when I click the edit button, it makes the selected row editable.
But when I click the update button I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
The code worked in the Forms application..

Is there any way the adapter.Update(userTable); will be able to work the same it worked in the forms application?

Can anybody please help me see my problem. If I can only get it to save the changes back to the .mdb file I would be extremely glad.

Comment: Did you check that the value of `adapter` is not null in the datagrid_RowUpdating method?

Comment: It is null, but I don't understand why? Because I do declare it and make an instance of it

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of private variables is different in web applications vs WinForms.
In short:
You should initialize the variables (Specifically the `adapter`)  in the the `Page_Load` method. It will then be not-null and you can use it.

Note: You will also need to store what changes were made in your dataset...
I recommend reading a little more about how it all works...
You can use the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) object for instance, or better yet, check the [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Understanding ASP.NET View State:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

IsPostBack:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx